# How do I keep the column used as groupby criteria (column 0)?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am grouping a pandas data frame by their value in column 0, which happens to be year, month column (formatted as a float64 like yy,mm).

Before using the groupby function, by dataframe is as follows:

```
          0     1     2     3       4   5   6      7      8    9
0     13,09  0.00   NaN  26.0  5740.0 NaN NaN    NaN    NaN   26
1     13,09  0.02   NaN  26.0  5738.0 NaN NaN    NaN    NaN   26
2     13,09  0.00   NaN  26.0  5738.0 NaN NaN    NaN    NaN   26
3     13,09  0.00   NaN  29.0     NaN NaN NaN    NaN    NaN   29
4     13,09  0.00   NaN  25.0     NaN NaN NaN    NaN    NaN   25
```

After running my groupby code (seen here)

```
month_year_total = month_year.groupby(0).sum()
```

I am given the following dataframe

```
           1       2       3         4    5    6       7       8      9 
0                                                                         
13,09   1.55     0.0   383.0   51583.0  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0    383   
13,10  12.56     0.0  2039.0  142426.0  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0   2039   
13,11   0.65  1890.0  1663.0  170038.0  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0   3553   
13,12   1.43  7014.0  1055.0  176217.0  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0   8069   
14,01   1.53  7284.0   856.0  101971.0  0.0  0.0     0.0     0.0   8140
```

I wish to keep column 0 when converting to numpy, as I intend it to be the x axis of my graph; however, the column is dropped when I convert data types. In fact, I cannot manipulate the column at all, even within the pandas dataframe.

How do I keep this column or add an identical column?

Comment: `month_year_total = month_year.groupby(0).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: or pass `as_index=False` to groupby. `month_year.groupby(0, as_index=False).sum()`